# How to make a view like the one below instead of using DataGridView?

Tags: c#, database, view

I'm making a college graded unit program in C# which is basically a database managing software. I'd like to incorporate a view like the one I've made in Photoshop instead of using DataGridView.

[image: Table view]

It is meant to be a list of contents which elements are clickable and after clicking the element, rest of them is pushed down and more details are shown on the darker field.

Here's the full image of it:

[image: Full Window]

Any guiding ideas?

Comment: I assume: WinForms? With that it's quite complicated to generate such modern looking UI, switch to WPF.

Comment: Did you try [searching in google](https://www.google.es/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23+winforms+datagridview+master+details)?

Comment: Winforms:  Nothing ready-made. - I would go for a ListView with owner/drawing. Maybe I would let it host a UserControl. Or have a look at this [DGV implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005397/accordion-in-windows-forms-datagridview/29006361?s=1|2.0746#29006361)

Comment: as @JanesAbouChleih said, it will be signifficantly easier with wpf, for example with ListView, with collapsible groups http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Reason_7._The_ListView.aspx You will also need to style your ScrollBar  https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37366/Styling-A-ScrollViewer-Scrollbar-In-WPF and http://www.nullskull.com/a/1525/styling-the-wpf-scrollviewer.aspx

Comment: Third party vendors like Telerik have grids that provide somewhat similar features.

Answer (score -1):

If you are planning a web based app for this then I would recommend you to use knockout.js for this purpose. I have been working with ASP.NET and I use knockout.js for making such tables.

For information on knockout.js you can checkout on http://knockoutjs.com/examples/collections.html

Comment: OP has made clear that this is **not** a web based app.