# Using tag in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to do something like this with windows forms:

[image]

Something like tags, but I only want label without colors and "x" value, I just want label with click event, how can I do it without using Telerik? it's not possible to do in datagrid view or something like that? Regards

Comment: Looks like you don't mean Tags but Tabs, yes? An owner-drawn Tab control maybe? Or a Label class that can draw itself a little rounded? Maybe added to a flowLayoutPanel? Your question is very unclear, so as it stands nobody will be able to help!

Comment: @TaW no, those look like tags to me. Many systems have textboxes where you can type text, and at the moment you type a comma behind it, it's looked up in an internal database of tags and transformed to a little coloured element like that.

Comment: @TaW You know... systems [including StackOverflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZBrp.png).

Comment: Yup, that is what I guessed as well. But in the framework context the name Tag is already taken ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Tag` is a very common `.Net` property, so the question is bit unclear. But looking at the image and taking a wild guess on what you may want..:

If you want to have the ability to add `Labels`, let's call them *TagLabels* during runtime you may want to use a `FlowLayoutPanel` as their container. It will allow adding more and will take care of the layout no matter what sizes they have.

Example:
[image]

To create them we can use a `TextBox`, which we add to the FLP first. Then we code its `PreviewKeyDown` event and let the user create a new *TagLabel* by pressing enter..:

```
private void textBox1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && textBox1.Text != "")
    {
        Label lbl = new Label {
            Text = "      " + textBox1.Text,  /* some room for the image */
            BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
            TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
            AutoSize = true,
            Margin = new Padding(2),
            ImageIndex = flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count % 
                         imageList1.Images.Count,
            ImageList = imageList1,
            ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft,
            MinimumSize = new Size(100, 20),
            BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow,
            Name = "TagLabel" + (flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count)
        };
        lbl.MouseClick +=lbl_MouseClick ;
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(lbl);
        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.SetChildIndex(lbl, 
                                  flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Count - 2);
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
    else
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

The `Click` event should be generic for all labels; so we first cast `sender` to `Label` and can then code the processing..:

```
private void lbl_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = sender as Label;
    //...
    MessageBox.Show(lbl.Name + " : Ouch! You clicked on " + lbl.Text.Trim());
}
```

This is just a basic piece of code. You can style the labels any way you want and of course also include code for deleting, maybe with a context menu. If those labels shall carry more responsibility, you can and should create a `class`, probably a `Label` subclass to hold further data and methods..

I'm also using an `ImageList` to display images to the left. Do change these details to suit your needs!

---

Note that there is no reasonable way to add the FLP to an ordinary `DataGridView`. You may be able to workaround but depending on your needs it may be best to keep them separate. DGVs have `Cells` and while these can hold special controls this is complicated and will always be restricted by the cells' i.e. the `Columns`' and the `Rows`' `Size`. As an alternative you can check out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005397/accordion-in-windows-forms-datagridview/29006361?s=1|43.5138#29006361) to see how you can insert virtual space to a row to hold a control but **neither DGV nor its Cells are `containers`.**