# Value in textbox on cell datagridview isn't changing when scroll

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a textbox usercontrol
Now I am doing a user control of datagridview, I add a usercontrol textbox into the cell of datagridview.
Then I dumped the data into datagridview, much data will appear scrolling, but when I scroll down, the data in textbox aren't changing, it should have displayed the data in the next sections. I need help to solve this problem.

I use the following code: For example, I added column (index = 7).

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);

    if (m.Msg.Equals(WM_NCPAINT))
    {
            for (int i = 0; i < this.RowCount; i++)
            {
                Rectangle cellRectangle = this.GetCellDisplayRectangle(7, i, true);
                var row = this.Rows[i];
                UCTextBox txt = new UCTextBox();
                txt.UCShowClear = false;
                txt.Visible = true;
                txt.ZText = row.Cells[7].Value.ToString();
                txt.Location = new Point(cellRectangle.X + 2, cellRectangle.Y + 1);
                txt.Size = new Size(cellRectangle.Width - 4, cellRectangle.Height - 4);
                this.Controls.Add(txt);
            }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46Siz.jpg)

Comment: _I add a usercontrol textbox into the cell of datagridview_ Show the code. Note that DGV Cells are really just virtual and are not controls. So adding a control to a DGV is not adding it to a Cell; so it won't scroll unless you add code.. - You may be interested to study [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005397/accordion-in-windows-forms-datagridview/29006361?r=SearchResults&s=1|43.3922#29006361)

Comment: Thanks for TaW's answer. I have updated more questions.