# I want to develop my own Dat Grid View for Win Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i want to develop my own data grid for Win From from scratch.
Data grid with features like 
Grouping 
sorting
filtering 
adding text row 
adding subtotal in between rows

I have tried using custom control but it becomes too slow when i add grouping and sorting and designing features

Now i am finding a way to design my own control.
In which basic language the win form controls are made.
like telerik dev express ? in which language these controls are made?

Comment: These are managed .NET controls written in C#. Was this your question?

Comment: Be warned that writing a capable data grid from scratch is easily month's worth of work.

Comment: _easily month's worth of work_ Conversion from programmer's estimate to wallclock time: *2 + 1 order, so 1 month => 2 years..

Comment: A month is being generous. There is a reason Infragistics or Telerik controls cost $1,000 or more there is a lot of work that goes into them. You will never be able to singlehandedly write a Grid with even close to the performance or number of features as one of the big companies

Comment: (...if not years)

Comment: If I needed to tackle that I would derive from a DGV and add the features I need. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005397/accordion-in-windows-forms-datagridview/29006361#29006361)

Comment: Yes i know thats a long project to build a data grid, but my application needs a rich featured data grid.

Comment: @dymanoid can you please tell me how to get started building .net managed controls ?

Comment: If you're asking such basic question as 'how to get started building .net managed controls' then i reckon building a fully featured datagrid control with all the functionality you require is overambitious...

Comment: Right clock project, select Add New Item, select User Control

Comment: There are plenty of ways to add "rich features" to an app which uses the existing control without resorting to a custom control.  Note also that the custom control may also require its own designer which can be another daunting project on its own.

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp Thanks, but i have tried that, i tried with custom control inherited from DataGridView but with all desired featured its working becomes too much slow, and most of all it flickers while scrolling. Thats why now i want to build my control very scratch

Comment: _(it) becomes too much slow_ __Very doubtful__. The proper question would then be: 'Why is this code slow?' You didn't make it [doublebuffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41893708/how-to-prevent-datagridview-from-flickering-when-scrolling-horizontally/41894210?r=SearchResults&s=1|55.1577#41894210) as you should have, right?

Comment: @TaW Yes i used that, actuallly after that it becomes good.

Comment: Does anyone of you have seen the Data Grid used by SAP in Sap Business One?
I want to develop a grid like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataGridView implementation spans thousands LOC.
Have a look for yourself https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/master/src/System.Windows.Forms/src/System/Windows/Forms/DataGridView.cs

It is not something you want to reimplement yourself.

Comment: Can i use that code to implement my customizations ?

Comment: You can. As long as you comply with the licensing terms under which the code is released.